# Java Criteria query for amount range regardless of amount sign

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, persistence, criteria-api

I want to perform search on db data based on amount range , there are some amount items which are negative as well . But I regardless of any sign I want to apply my criteria on actual amount using javax.persistence.criteria .

E.g. query input : between 1 and 100

Expected output : -99 ,-10 , 33 ,90 100

Can anyone guide me on this ?

Comment: you mean using `ABS(field)` ? Please explain why that is difficult and what you have tried

Comment: Hi, I want jpa criteria predicate for following query  : select * from Table where abs(cast(amount as decimal(10,2))) between 1 and 800.

Comment: so what have you tried ? which particular part of that is hard? there are methods on CriteriaBuilder for all of those (abs, cast, between). Oh, and put that in YOUR QUESTION, not in comments

Comment: Hey , Manage to handle cast using predicate but I  don't have clue about how to apply abs on this predicate .. Predicate matchPrice = cb.between(trxRoot.get("amount").as(BigDecimal.class), minPrice, toAmount);

Comment: @BillyFrost Thanks for your suggestion and help. I figured out it...

Answer (score 1):

Sql Query :

```
select * from table where abs(cast(amount as decimal(10,2))) between 1 and 700
```

Criteria Query :

```
final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
Predicate matchPrice = cb.between(cb.abs(trxRoot.get("amount").as(BigDecimal.class)), minPrice, toAmount);
predicates.add(matchPrice);
query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
```